# flyway : Powershell and flywaydb

Tags: flyway

I was wondering if anybody has any experience using flyway with powershell?

I'm trying to create a script that will run flyway on different servers\instances depending on the parameters chosen in the powershell prompts - however I'm struggling to get it working! Has anybody tried this before?

Is there a particular switch to use when running the flyway migrate command that will pick up a certain config file in a specific folder so that flyway runs against a specific server, database or instance?

Admittedly I'm new to using flyway so any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-configFile=...` param: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/#configFile